# Java card method header

Tags: javacard

This is my first time here on Stackoverflow. My question is how the Java card virtual machine constructs the header for the methods?

Here is an example of a simple method:

```
method_info[1] // @0043= {
    // flags     : 0
    // max_stack : 5
    // nargs     : 3
    // max_locals: 0
    /*0045*/ L0:   new             0x0003
    /*0048*/       dup             
    /*0049*/       aload_0         
    /*004a*/       sload_1         
    /*004b*/       sload_2         
    /*004c*/       invokespecial   0x0004
    /*004f*/       pop             
    /*0050*/       return
```

How do we obtain **max_stack : 5**?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, may I know why do you want to know this?

Comment: And for your question, did you took a look at JCVM Specification?

Comment: What is the source code of this method?

Comment: @Abraham i am a phd student and i have a problem on this, also i already read specification and found no thing.

Comment: @vojta if i know the source code i have the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from *Java Card Virtual Machine Specification v 2.2.2*:

> **max_stack**
>
> **The *max_stack* item indicates the maximum number of 16-bit
>   cells required on  the operand stack during execution of this method.**
>   Stack entries of type int are represented in two 16-bit cells, while
>   all others are  represented in one 16-bit cell.

Lets take a look at your example:

```
/*0045*/ L0:   new             0x0003
/*0048*/       dup   
/*0049*/       aload_0         
/*004a*/       sload_1         
/*004b*/       sload_2
```

And we have this for your example:

> **new** : Create new object
>
> Description :  The unsigned indexbyte1 and indexbyte2 are used to
>   construct an index into the  constant pool of the current package
>   (Section 3.5, “Frames” on page 3-3), where the  value of the index is
>   (indexbyte1 << 8) | indexbyte2. The item at that index in the 
>   constant pool must be of type CONSTANT_Classref (Section 6.7.1, 
>   “CONSTANT_Classref” on page 6-16), a reference to a class or interface
>   type. The  reference is resolved and must result in a class type (it
>   must not result in an interface  type). Memory for a new instance of
>   that class is allocated from the heap, and the  instance variables of
>   the new object are initialized to their default initial values. **The 
>   objectref, a reference to the instance, is pushed onto the operand
>   stack.**
>
> ---
>
> **dup** : Duplicate top operand stack word
>
> Description : **The top word on the operand stack is duplicated and pushed onto  the operand stack.** The dup instruction must not be used unless **word contains a 16-bit data type.**
>
> ---
>
> **aload_n** : Load reference from local variable
>
> Description : The *n* must be a valid index into the local variables of
>   the current frame  (Section 3.5, “Frames” on page 3-3). The local
>   variable at *n* must contain a  `reference`. **The objectref in the local
>   variable at *n* is pushed onto the operand stack.**
>
> ---
>
> **sload_n** : Load shorts from local variable
>
> Description : The *n* must be a valid index into the local variables of
>   the current frame  (Section 3.5, “Frames” on page 3-3). The local
>   variable at *n* must contain a `short`.  **The value in the local variable
>   at *n* is pushed onto the operand stack.**

As each one of the above object need 16 bit in the stack, we have the following max_stack for this example:

16 bit for `new`

16 bit for `dup`

16 bit for `aload_0`

16 bit for `sload_1`

16 bit for `sload_2`

And so:

**max_stack** = `(16+ 16 + 16 + 16 + 16) / 16 =` **5**.

*Note: I'm not sure about my answer, adding some more example is useful to make us sure.*

Comment: thanks for your answer, you are right.
but my problem now how can i calculate the max_stack starting from method bottom like this:
{
return 
pop
invokespecial   0x0004
sload_2
sload_1
aload_0 
dup
new             0x0003
}

Comment: @nobody001 Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. would you please explain the question more clearly?